# Django Rest Framework Displaying Serialized data through Views.py

Tags: serialization, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class International(object):
    """ International Class that stores versions and lists 
        countries
    """
    def __init__(self, version, countrylist):

        self.version = version
        self.country_list = countrylist

class InternationalSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """ Serializer for International page 
        Lists International countries and current version
    """
    version = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    country_list = CountrySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

I have a serializer set up this way, and I wish to display serialized.data (which will be a dictionary like this: { "version": xx, and "country_list": [ ] } ) using views.py

I have my views.py setup this way:

```
class CountryListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """ Endpoint : somedomain/international/
    """

    ## want to display a dictionary like the one below

    {
       "version": 5
       "country_list" : [ { xxx } , { xxx } , { xxx } ]

    }
```

What do I code in this CountryListView to render a dictionary like the one above? I'm really unsure.

Comment: Does your view require pagination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 class CountryListView(generics.ListAPIView):
        """ Endpoint : somedomain/international/
        """

       def get(self,request):

          #get your version and country_list data and
          #init your object
          international_object = International(version,country_list)
          serializer = InternationalSerializer(instance=international_object)
          your_data = serializer.data
          return your_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build on the idea from here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#example

> Suppose we want to replace the default pagination output style with a modified format that includes the next and previous links under in a nested 'links' key. We could specify a custom pagination class like so:
>
> ```python
> class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
>     def get_paginated_response(self, data):
>         return Response({
>             'links': {
>                'next': self.get_next_link(),
>                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
>             },
>             'count': self.page.paginator.count,
>             'results': data
>         })
> ```

As long as you don't need the pagination, you can setup a custom pagination class which would pack your response in whichever layout you may need:

```python
class CountryListPagination(BasePagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return {
            'version': 5,
            'country_list': data
        }
```

Then all you need to do is to specify this pagination to your class based view:

```python
class CountryListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    # Endpoint : somedomain/international/
    pagination_class = CountryListPagination
```

Let me know how is this working for you.